# Optimal extended class naming convention?

Tags: php, oop, namespaces, package

Which of the following naming conventions is most used/accepted, or which is most optimal for most projects? I'm having a hard time deciding.

```
Base class: \Model
Sub class: \Model\User

Base class: \Model\Model
Sub class: \Model\User

Base class: \Model\Base
sub class: \Model\User
```

So in other words, should I put the base class in the same namespace as the subclasses, and should I call it something constant like "base" or should it just have the same name as the namespace?

Comment: Some thoughts on namespacing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/431911/namespace-rule-of-thumb

Answer (score 3):

Honestly, I always put the base class in the same directory as the sub classes, inless the base class is intended as part of a multi-application framework, in which case it would go in a generic library library,

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how PHP handles namespaces/packages, but in other languages there are benefits to keeping things in the same packages.  I'm thinking specifically, of the ability to use Java's `default` and `protected` access modifiers, or C++'s `friend` keyword.  These might not be possible/as straightforward once you start separating abstracts into a different package from concretes.

Answer (score 0):

I like the Zend Framework naming convention. If it don't seems very easy at first, it's very maintainable.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/coding-standard.naming-conventions.html